# Showing a subset of Z15 is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't get any ideas for this question because to me, it's look so complicated to proof the conditions of being a group. I would appreciate some help.
Let G be the following subset of Z15, namely {3, 6, 9, 12}. Show that G is a
group under multiplication in Z15. Find the identity, and the inverse of each group
element.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) and try to show some efforts as much as you can.

Comment: I'm in the first lessons of Abstract Algebra. Please answer the question with simple definitions. thanks

Comment: That's your job to show that at least you made the effort to look up the definitions, and explain why you still have trouble. "Meet you half the way."

Comment: No. there is no 0 in the subgroup. @saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

Under the ring isomorphism
$$(3\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z) \to \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$$
$$3a \mapsto 3a$$

the set $\{3,6,9,12\}$ corresponds to the set of invertible elements $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Thus:

- it forms a group under multiplication
- the identity is the preimage of $1 = 3 \cdot 2$, which is $6$.
- the element of order $2$ is $-1=3\cdot3=9$, and the two elements that are left ($3,12$) have to be inverses of each other.

Comment: I'm in the first lesson of Abstract Algebra and we haven't read the isomorphism and that kinda stuff. Would you mind answer the question with basic definitions? Thanks for your attention and effort :) @barto

Comment: Then you're probably supposed to compute the Cayley table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table and read from it which element is the identity, etc.  I don't feel like doing that here, I'm sorry. I hope the answer will be helpful later!